# Gathering details of Annotation Subclass from ArcGIS Pro map.ListLayers() objects

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, annotation

I am attempting to remove all Annotation Subclass layers from a list that is generated from a Map inside of ArcGIS Pro.
From what I can tell the subclasses must be a "Layer" inside of Pro.

I cannot find a method to conclusively distinguish which layers are annotation subclasses.

```
l = [list of Layer Objects]
for x in l:
    if x:
        try:
            desc = arcpy.Describe(x)
            print (desc.featureClass.featuretype)
        except:
            print (f"{x} cannot be described")
```

This will yield "Annotation" for both the Annotation layer, and its subclasses.

```
desc.name
```

This will yield the Name of the Annotation layer for all subclasses

```
for x in l:
    print (x)
```

generates an error **NameError: The attribute 'longName' is not supported on this instance of Layer** as soon as it hits the Annotation subclass

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  Please [edit] your question to include a snippet of the code you've tried and details of the result when you run it.  Explain what you mean by "the properties... for the subclasses are odd"

Answer (score 1):

You could use a process of elimination to determine whether your annotation layer is a subclass or not.  The Annotation layer itself will return a `True` if you query `isFeatureLayer`, but on the subclass it will error.

Now I'm not a fan of using `try` and `except` to determine values, but in this case you could catch that error to determine which layer is the subclass.

```
for layer in layers:
    desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
    if desc.featureType == "Annotation":
        print(layer.name)
        try:
            if layer.isFeatureLayer:
                x = "Annotation Class Layer"
        except:
            x = "Annotation Subclass Layer"
        print(x)
```

gives the result

```
'My Annotation'
Annotation Class Layer
'Class 1'
Annotation Subclass Layer
'Class 2'
Annotation Subclass Layer
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have more or less done the same thing, using different properties that the Subclasses dont happen to have. my concern is that this doesnt explicitly find the subclasses which would be ideal.